# How to use MudDateRangePicker in blazor server using web api

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-web-api2, mudblazor

I want to filter or search the DATE from this (date) to this (date) using MudDateRangePicker in MudBlazor in my database. I get a bad request, and there seems to be an error in my code. Can someone help me fix this? Thank you. Sorry for my English."

ClearanceServices.cs

```
 public async Task<List<clearance>> SearchDateClearance(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        List<clearance> xclearance = new();
        try
        {
            using (var con = new MySqlConnection(_constring.GetConnection()))
            {
                await con.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var com = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM clearance WHERE DATE(date) >= @start AND DATE(date) <= @end", con)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                };
                com.Parameters.Clear();
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end);

                using (var rdr = await com.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    while (await rdr.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                    {
                        xclearance.Add(new clearance
                        {
                            clear_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["clear_id"].ToString()),
                            res_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["res_id"].ToString()),
                            photo = (byte[])rdr["photo"],
                            name = rdr["name"].ToString(),
                            age = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["age"].ToString()),
                            status = rdr["status"].ToString(),
                            purok = rdr["purok"].ToString(),
                            request = rdr["request"].ToString(),
                            date = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["date"]),
                            fee = Convert.ToDouble(rdr["fee"]),
                            receipt = rdr["receipt"].ToString(),
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle the exception
        }
        return xclearance;
    }
}
```

ClearanceController.cs

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<clearance>> SearchDateClearance(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        var ret = await xservices.SearchDateClearance(start, end);
        return ret;
    }
```

ClearancePage.razor

```
@page "/"
 <MudDateRangePicker @ref="_picker" Label="Select Date From - To" @bind-DateRange="_dateRange">
            <PickerActions>
                <MudButton Class="mr-auto align-self-start" OnClick="@(() => _picker.Clear())">Clear</MudButton>
                <MudButton OnClick="@(() => _picker.Close(false))">Cancel</MudButton>
                <MudButton Color="Color.Primary" @onclick="SearchDate">Ok</MudButton>
            </PickerActions>
        </MudDateRangePicker>

@code{
 private DateRange _dateRange = new DateRange();
 private async Task SearchDate()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{Nav.BaseUri}");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await localStorage.GetItemAsStringAsync("token"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"api/Clearance/SearchDateClearance?start={_dateRange:yyyy-MM-dd}&end={_dateRange:yyyy-MM-dd}");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string contentrespose = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            clearancelist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<clearance[]>(contentrespose);
        }
        else
        {
            Snackbar.Add($"Warning: {response.StatusCode}", Severity.Warning);
        }
    }
    StateHasChanged();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the MudDateRangePicker code

```
 <MudDateRangePicker  
           Label="Select Date From - To" 
           DateRange="_dateRange" 
           DateRangeChanged="@(value =>{
                 _dateRange = value; 
                 SearchDate(); })" 
           DateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```

Then i add Start.value & End.Value in my api

```
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"api/Clearance/SearchDateClearance?start={_dateRange.Start.Value:yyyy-MM-dd}&end={_dateRange.End.Value:yyyy-MM-dd}");
```